# class inheritance erroring out?

Tags: c++, qt

I get 2 sets of errors when trying to build:

(on the first build)

```
In constructor 'aa::aa(int)':
no matching function for call to 'bb:bb()'
candidates are: bb::bb(int)
bb:bb(const bb&)
```

(then I hit build again and get the following)

```
file not recognized: File truncated... takes me to assembly
collect2:ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

```
#ifndef BB_H
#define BB_H

class bb
{
public:
    bb(int _m);
    int m;
};

#endif // BB_H
```

---

```
#ifndef AA_H
#define AA_H
#include "AA/bb.h"

class aa :  bb
{

public:
    aa(int _i);

    int i;
    int j;
};

#endif // AA_H
```

---

```
#include "bb.h"

bb::bb(int _m)
{
    m = _m * 5;
}
```

---

```
#include "aa.h"

aa::aa(int _i)
{
    i = _i;
    j = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: You need to use an initializer list to initialize the base. This should be addressed in any book or inheritance tutorial.

Comment: In case you don't get what chris is talking about: The derived constructor will call the base class default construtor `bb:bb()`. Since you didn't specify `bb:bb()` it cannot construct an object of `aa` (it doesn't know how to construct its base). However, you can specify that `aa::aa(int)` should use `bb::bb(int)`: aa:aa(int _i): bb(_i) { /* ... */}`. The details can be found in any decent book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In constructor 'aa::aa(int)':
no matching function for call to 'bb:bb()'
```

The compiler's right.  You don't have a default constructor.  Even though the compiler will write a default constructor for you if you don't write one, this doesn't happen if you have *any* user-defined constructors.

You have 2 choices:

First, implement a default constructor:

```
class bb
{
public:
    bb(int _m);
    bb();
    int m;
};

bb:bb()
{
}
```

This is maybe gross because how will you initialize `m`?

Second, call the convert constructor in `aa`'s constructor, using an initialization list:

```
aa::aa(int _i)
:
  bb (_i)
{
    i = _i;
    j = i + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Base class constructor gets called when a derived class object is created.**

In your example you must have created an object of class aa, since class bb is its base class, the compiler searches for the default constructor of bb class. As you have created a parameterized constructor it wont provide any default constructor leading to the error 
No matching for the function call to bb(). 
 To overcome that error either provide a default constructor in class bb like

```
    bb::bb()
    {
    }
```

or 

In the aa constructor initialization list just give a call to class bb parameterized constructor like below

```
    aa::aa(int i):bb(int x)
    {
    }
```

What i did here was, i have just initialized the data members of base class before initializing the data members of derived class, And the compiler expects the same.